# Stack Overflow error when trying to access the list in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have a problem: In this function wirtten in Dart(for an application in Flutter), when I try to access the taskList, it throws a "Stack Overflow" exception, but I don't understand why. Even if I call up the list and try to access it from other parts of the code, it generates the same exception. Furthermore, everything was working fine until yesterday and I don't seem to have written anything to interact with taskList.
Do you have any ideas on how to solve the problem?

```
 static Future<void> FetchTasks() async{
    try{

      final data = await Supabase.instance.client.from('Task').select();
      for(var element in data)
      {

        taskList.add(Task(element['Nome'].toString(), element['PK_TakId'] as int));
      }

    }catch(e){
      print("It was not possible to download data from the DB for the following reason: $e");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show your Task constructor

Comment: hii please provide the complete code with error so that anyone can understand and answer it.